# Reading PDF using PyPDF2 not resulting anything

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

Here is my code - courtesy - http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511465-pure-python-pdf-to-text-converter/ .
I modified it to include next version of PyPDF.

```
import PyPDF2

def getPDFContent(path):
    content = ""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
    # Iterate pages
    print "Number of pages is ", pdf.getNumPages()

    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
        print (content)

    # Collapse whitespace
    content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
    return content

print getPDFContent("RL.pdf").encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace")
```

The file I am reading is here.
http://dmc.kar.nic.in/RL.pdf

All I get is this.

Number of pages is  1
Blank after this.

Is this a problem with the PDF or am I going wrong somewhere?
All help appreciated!

Comment: What is `file` ? You might have meant to use `open` here.

Comment: Tried changing it to open. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file turned out to be corrupt.